# Pipenv installed, but "doesn't exist"

Tags: windows, pip, pipenv

i'm trying to install **pipenv** on Windows 10 to use it with Docker, i've done the following steps on my Command Line:

- `pip install pipenv`
  ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChkVs.png))
- `pipenv`
  [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R59on.png) (*translation: "pipenv" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*)

So Windows tells me *pipenv* is not installed. How is it possible? How i can fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is add python to the window system variable. If you haven't done that, follow these steps:

1. Type "variable" to the search bar and select "Edit the system variable".
2. Click on  the "environment variable..." button and you should see the list of variables that has been added by window.
3. Select the one containing  the word "path" and click "edit".
4. Click the new and you can add the path to which you installed python.

For example:

My python is at

```
c:\python
```

Copy that and put into the edit box and click OK.
Lastly, click OK again and you should be good to go.

After you did that, you can do this to your command line:

```
python pipenv
```

Note: make sure you have pipenv installed by pip.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  Tried everything that has been recommended here and elsewhere.
Verified that Pip was in path
Python39 runs fine
PyCharm runs fine.

Finally, right clicked on Python in my list of programs in Windows10 and selected modify
Checked the various boxes during the modify dialog.

Pip now loads and works fine.